# Pygame audio not looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

I wish to create a game, and im trying to make a music system.
Unfortunately i have been stuck with the loop part of the music system.

I tried:

```py
from pygame.mixer import music as music
from pygame import mixer as mixer
    def song_loop(self):
        global looping
        if playing:
            if not looping:
                pos = music.get_pos()
                print(pos)
                music.stop()
                music.play(loops=-1)
                music.set_pos(pos)
                self.song_loop_btt.configure(text="")
            else:
                pos=music.get_pos()
                print(pos)
                music.stop()
                music.play(loops=0)
                music.set_pos(pos)
        looping = not looping
```

What happens:
The music plays from the start and loops.
What i expect to happen:
The music stops, and loops from the position where it was when `song_loop` was called.
Context:
The `song_loop` function is called by a custom tkinter `CTkButton` Object as a callback.
I also wish to be able to play .ogg, .mp3, .wav and other formats that are supported by pygame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code(It's technically the same with a little change):

```
if playing:
    if not looping:
        pos = music.get_pos()
        music.stop()
        music.play(loops=-1, start=pos) //a little change
        looping = True
        self.song_loop_btt.configure(text="")
```

Comment: Arent they the same? and can you please provide an example?

Comment: I didn't knew that my bad lol @TheSysKill I thought they both are different

Comment: tried it, both  dont work.

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid lol i should have used `rewind()`
if someone has the same problem i hope they see this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).